# What does these errors means?

Tags: apt, gnupg

I got this before that if flushed the apt-cache:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease [115 kB]                                                                                                
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                                      
Get:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1 811 B]                                                                                                  
Get:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt groovy-pgdg InRelease [16,8 kB]                                                                                           
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease                                                                                                       
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease                                                                                                        
Ign:9 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                               
Get:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease [36,2 kB]                                                                                               
Hit:11 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                                                                                                                
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release                                                                                                        
Hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release                                                                                                         
Hit:14 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease                                                                                        
Hit:15 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                            
Ign:6 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease                                  
Hit:17 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial Release                                                
Hit:16 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease                                                      
Err:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_InRelease into data and signature failed
Err:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt groovy-pgdg InRelease
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/apt.postgresql.org_pub_repos_apt_dists_groovy-pgdg_InRelease into data and signature failed
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_groovy-updates_InRelease into data and signature failed
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                           
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: GPG error: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt groovy-pgdg InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/apt.postgresql.org_pub_repos_apt_dists_groovy-pgdg_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt groovy-pgdg InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_groovy-updates_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have solved but i wonder does someone knows what these errors means?
I don't need any solution just to interpret these error-messages?

Comment: At this stage, `apt` is downloading lists of available packages, and verifying their versions against a hash. The error messages probably mean that the downloads failed and the files were only partially downloaded, causing the verification to fail. Probably just a network glitch. A second attempt would probably have succeeded.

Comment: Thank you @Jos :)!